# Cameras to the Delhi airport

Tags: customs-and-immigration, india, electronic-items, new-delhi

I would be carrying two cameras, two watches, a tablet and a Kindle to the Delhi airport.

Do you think there would be a problem?

Comment: What sort of problem? Be more specific. Please **edit more info into the question**.

Comment: What is the dollar value of these items?

Comment: [Taking two DSLR cameras to India](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/117957/1810)