# Taking two DSLR cameras to India

Tags: customs-and-immigration

I am going back to India and I have two DSLR camera. Am I allowed to take two camera without any restriction?. Both the cameras are used one.

Comment: Are these cameras that you purchased abroad and are bringing back? If so, you'll need to pay import duties.

Comment: That duplicate is out of date right now but mostly the principals for importing goods do not change, the value will be adjusted every year or few years.